# Custom edge drawing function in vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js-network, vis.js

I'm using the [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) library to draw a network but I need to customize the way the edges are drawn. For example, I would like to draw let's say 50% of the edge in red and the other 50% in blue.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a way to do it:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet
([
    {id: 1, label: '1'},
    {id: 2, label: '2'},
]);

var edges = new vis.DataSet
([
    {from: 1, to: 2, color:'red'},
]);

var graph = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
var network = new vis.Network(container, graph, options);
var percent = 50;
network.on("afterDrawing", function (ctx)
{
    var pos = network.getPositions([1, 2]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.filStyle = 'green';
    ctx.moveTo(pos[1].x, pos[1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(pos[1].x + (pos[2].x-pos[1].x)*percent/100, pos[1].y + (pos[2].y - pos[1].y)*percent/100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly customize parts of an edge but you can create two different edges (each with its own style) using a dummy invisible node serving as a connector. Since the dummy node is invisible, the two edges are going to look like two parts of the same edge.

For example, say you want to connect two nodes with a half-green-half-red edge:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: '1'},
    {id: 2, label: '2'},
    {id: 'dummy', hidden: true}
]);

var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 'dummy', color:'red'},
    {from: 'dummy', to: 2, color:'green'}
]);

var graph = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the idea behind this was to show a 'progress bar' represented by the edge, which your answer does not really allow to do.

Comment: For OP : The question does not provide enough information for this answer to be wrong. If you want something else than a 50/50, you should have stated it in your question.